# Characterizing a certain kind of bifurcation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I'm dealing with the following ODE,

$$
\left(\frac{dr}{d\lambda}\right)^2 = \left[1 + \frac{(C - 1)M}{(2r - 3M)}\right]\left[1 - \left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)\left(\frac{D}{r}\right)^2\right] \equiv f(r;C,D)\,\, ,
$$

where

$$
r \in \mathbb{R^{+}} \quad \textrm{and} \quad C,D,M \in \mathbb{R} \,\, .
$$

Taking as bifurcation parameters $C$ and $D$, I wish to describe the bifurcations ocurring in this system, for this I used the following system to get the bifurcation curve,

$$
f(r;C,D) = 0 \,\, , \\
f_{r}(r;C,D) = 0 \,\, , 
$$

Which gives me the following curve,

[image: Bifurcation plot]

Which suggests to me that there is a kind of cusp and saddle-node bifurcation here, but the conditions for saddle-node fail. On the other hand, the conditions for a cusp bifurcation holds, even though the non degenerancy conditions fail too. My question is, this bifurcation curve tells me that there is a more complex bifurcation happening here, not just a cusp one, which kind of bifurcation could be happening here? Especifically, I would like to know what kind of bifurcations goes in the black points. The $(r,C,D)$-coordinates of these points considering $M = 1$ are

$$
p_{1} = (3, -2, 3\sqrt{3}) \,\, , \\
p_{2} = (3, -2, -3\sqrt{3}) \,\, , \\
p_{3} = (0, 4, 0) \,\, , \\
p_{4} = (-6, 16, -3\sqrt{3}) \,\, , \\
p_{5} = (-6, 16, 3\sqrt{3}) \,\, .
$$

Those with $r < 0$ are not in the domain of the system, but I would like to know the bifurcation anyway.

Comment: Can you clarify few more details about your final plot? What does exactly color means here? In theory, having two equations with three unknowns allows you to find parametrization $(C(r), D(r))$ for solution branches, which must be 1d curves. Do these orange and purple curves correspond to branches?

Comment: @Evgeny yeas, they are curves parametrized by r, there’s nothing special with the colors!

Comment: Okay, another question: are you trying to determine the type of bifurcation points which are marked by black dots? Or there are problems with determining types of curves outside of intersection points?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to determine the bifurcation in the black points

Comment: It seems like one of the curves is $f(r;C,D) =0$ and the other curve is $f_{r}(r;C,D) =0$, is it? if so which curve correspond to $f(r;C,D) = 0$ ? also I observe that you mark a black point where the purple curve touches the orange curve, if so then what about the black point at $C < 5 ,D = 0$ ?

Comment: @BAYMAXI think that point will be a bifurcation obtained when changing the parameter $C$...These curves is just the solution of the system of equations given in the OP. It was get eliminating r from the equations, the diference of the colors is due the software I used to plot, I'm going to edit the post in order to avoid confusion. By the way, the horizontal line is the value of the critical $D=3\sqrt{3}$, exactly where goes the bifurcation.

Comment: @HerrSchrödinger I see can you also include the equations and how you eliminated $'r'$? also if possible we can discuss this in [Dynamical Systems and Chaos theory chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55403/dynamical-systems-and-chaos-theory)

Comment: You know, I don't get where the orange straight lines come from. I plugged them into the expressions for $f(r; C, D)$ and $f_{r}(r; C, D)$  in SymPy and neither of them gone zero. Can you explain this bit? Also, SymPy gave me only one solution curve: $ C = 4 - \frac{2r}{M}, \quad D^{2} = \frac{r^{3}}{- 2 M + r}$. Just by the look I presume this is a purple curve on your plot.

Comment: @HerrSchrödinger Nevermind, I had found previous comments and now I see where orange line comes from :) Still, would be nice to verify if you have the same solution as mine.

Comment: @Evgeny We got exactly the same equations for the bifurcation curves!

Comment: @HerrSchrödinger Perfect! You've mentioned that non-degeneracy condition fails here, I want to check if we are on the same page. If I specifically check equilibrium $r = 3M$ wheh $C = 4 - 2 \frac{r}{M}$ and $D^{2} = \frac{r^{3}}{-2 M + r} $ (this corresponds to a codimension two bifurcation that you are trying to understand), the first and the second derivatives of RHS are zero at it, but the third derivative is $\frac{36}{r^3}$. According to [Kuznetsov](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~dturaev/kuznetsov.pdf), it means that non-degeneracy condition C.1 (see p. 303) is met. Did you mean the same?

Comment: @Evgeny Yeah, this condition holds, but C.2 fails, unfortunately. However, is not it a codimension two bifurcation? My guess is that it is not possible to characterize this more "general bifurcation" as a cuspid once this is a codimension one bifurcation.